# Error 800A0401 in code to speak text

Tags: vbscript

I am getting error 800A0401.

```
Dim message.Sapi
message=InputBox("enter the text to b 

spoken!","#speakup!")
set Sapi = Create Object("SAPI.Spvoice")
Sapi.speak message
```

I use this code to speak some text for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim message, sapi
message=InputBox("enter the text to be spoken!","Speak to Me")
Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
sapi.Speak message
```

Try To Use this and save it in .vbs file